# Connect Django with SAP Hana

Tags: django, hana

I'm trying to connect django with a SAP Hana DB. I've installed a backend as described in github: https://github.com/kapilratnani/django_hana
and
configured the settings.py as specified:

```
'data_source': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.django_hana',# I tried also 'django_hana' or 'hello' with the same results
        'NAME': 'IOT',
        'USER': 'ALEX',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': '186.47.255.17',
        'PORT': '30015',
    }
```

I'm getting a connection error, as if it is not recognizing the Engine: I get the same error if I type 'hello' in the engine. Here is the error:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fc2a959f0c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1172, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_long_column_names())
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1587, in _check_long_column_names
    connection = connections[db]
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/django/Env/singolar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 135, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.django_hana' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named django_hana.base
```

Any ideas why it's not recognizing the Engine?

Comment: with the mysql engine it works fine: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',

Comment: Found repository that supports Django 1.9 and resolves the error: 
https://github.com/mathebox/django_hana_pyhdb

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found repository that supports Django 1.9 and resolves the error: github.com/mathebox/django_hana_pyhdb

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...